# Appengine cloud SQL performance issue, taking too much time to process the request

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

In my django project I am using app-engine with cloud SQL, the problem I am facing is a significant performance issue, app-engine is taking too much time to process the request (like 3-4 minutes). When I looked at the trace it's showing a latency below 1.5 seconds, which was expected.

My app-engine is of F1 instance class Min Idle Instances, Max Idle Instances and Max Concurrent Requests as auto, and cloud SQL is a High memory machines with 2CPU 13GB memory.

And it's happening even if I am the only user in the project, I don't know where I am going wrong can anyone help me ?